# how to update model from the Route function

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write small search application but am struck at updating the model based on some action.

### Modified code

adapters/application.js

```
   import DS from 'ember-data';
   export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
       host: 'http://c6403:2222',
       namespace: 'server'
   });
```

---

serializers/results.js

```
  import DS from 'ember-data';

  export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(payload) {
    return {
      title: payload.title,
      description: payload.description,
      type: payload.type,
      url: payload.url,
     };
   }
  });
```

---

model/results.js:

```
    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default  DS.Model.extend({

     title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string'),
   searchText: DS.attr('string')
 });
```

---

templates/index.js

```
      {{search-home  action="submitsearch"}}
      {{search-list searchlist=model}}
```

---

templates/components/search-list.hbs

```
   {{#each searchlist as | searchItem|}}
      <li>{{searchItem.title}}</li>
     <li>{{searchItem.description}}</li>
     <li>{{searchItem.url}}</li>
    {{/each}}
```

route/index.js:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function (params){
       return [
        {
        title: 'Rails is Omakase1',
       description: 'Lorem ipsum',
       url: 'google.com',
       type: 'sf'
     },
     {
        title: 'Rails is Omakase2',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum',
        url: 'google.com',
        type: 'sf'
     }
   ]
 },

 actions:{

   submitsearch: function(searchText) {
     this.get('store').query('results', { searchText });
     this.refresh();
   }
  }
```

### });

search-list.hbs:

```
 <ul>
  {{#each searchlist as | searchItem|}}
    <li>{{searchItem.title}}</li>
    <li>{{searchItem.description}}</li>
    <li>{{searchItem.url}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

---

My JSON response

```
     [
      {
       "url":"https://login.salesforce.com/",
       "title":"This is SF KB",
       "description":"This is SF HCC",
      "type":"SF"
     },
      {
     "url":"https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa",
      "title":"This is SF JIRA",
       "description":"This is SF HCC",
       "type":"JIRA"
      }
   ]
```

---

---

When I submit my search -  I could see it is invoking JSON call and pulling out the data from the server. but i see error as "***Assertion Failed: The response to store.query is expected to be an array but it was a single record. Please wrap your response in an array or use `store.queryRecord` to query for a single record.
Error***"

Can you please point me what mistake am doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Let ember-data do the magic for you:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    submitSearch(searchText) {
      this.get('store').query('index', { searchText });
    }
  },
  model() {
    /*
     * Retrieve all available record in store for model.
     * If you allready have search criteria (e.g. from query params)
     * you might want to use `query` method of ember-data.
     * If you don't want to make a call to server before user
     * enters search criteria just use stores `peekAll` method.
     * By the way "index" is a very confusing name for a model.
     */
    return this.get('store').findAll('index');
  }
});
```

Your routes model are all *index* records available in store. If you retrieve new records from store by calling `this.get('store').query()` or similar methods they are pushed in store and retrieved by your model.

Note that you might have to write an adapter and maybe an serializer for your api endpoint.

**Update**: Feels like a new question but as a short hint: There is no `normalizePayload` hook im ember-data 2.x. It was deprecated in 1.13 and removed in 2.x. I guess you are looking for `normalizeRecord`.

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply. as you have advised I modified my code to make the adpater/model do the json request. but am seeing some error. could you please point me what mistake am doing there? (I have UP voted your comment)

Comment: Are you using ember-data 1.x? I'm asking cause `normalizePayload` method of `DS.RestSerializer` was deprecated in 1.13 and removed in 2.x.

Comment: am using 2.11.0 version, i tried to use like below below that also does not work

           import DS from 'ember-data';

         export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

        });